# Which CPEX Callbacks should I use to solve a sub-problem and use result to help the main-problem as lazy constraints?

Tags: callback, cplex

I am working on an MIP problem on CPLEX. The main model objective is to minimize a function, say min f(x).

The following steps are the idea of what I want to do:

1. I want to pause or terminate after it find a feasible solution -- for this, I use cplex.parameters.mip.limits.solutions.set(1) to stop the solver
2. Then I want to create and  solve another sub-problem, say to min g(x), in which the solution of g(x) is a part of constraints of the main model.
3. After obtaining the solution to the sub-problem, I add a constraint to the main problem using adding constraints or probably the lazy constraint callback.
4. Finally, the main model has become a new and better model that I can solve for a solution.

**However, I want to perform the step 1) to 4) iteratively until the main model is optimal.**

I have not accomplished doing this since it is complicated. If anyone can guide, point me to the right direction, or give me some examples, I will be very appreciated.

Comment: I have seen the admipex and bendersatsp files, they are examples for using callback in CPLEX. However, I am still not sure which callbacks that I should use. My idea is to use BranchCallback to get information from the feasible solution to create a sub-problem in step 2., use LazyConstraintCallback to add constraints obtained from the sub-problem, and use SolveCallback to tell CPLEX to work uninterruptedly with self.use_solution().

Comment: From the syntax you use in your question it looks like you are using the CPLEX Python API. Is that correct? It sounds like you could do this using the new [generic callback](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.studio.help/CPLEX/ReleaseNotes/topics/releasenotes128/newCallbacks.html) which was introduced in CPLEX 12.8. The `bendersatsp2.py` example should show you what you need, I think.

Comment: Thanks, rkersh! This is the first time that I am working on CPLEX and I am using CPEX Python API. I will look into the new generic callback.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is exactly the situation in which a lazy constraint callback can be used: That callback is invoked whenever CPLEX finds a new candidate feasible solution. You can inspect this solution. If it violates some of your constraint, you can add them and CPLEX will discard the solution. If the solution is feasible you just let it pass and CPLEX will use as new incumbent.

You can implement a lazy constraint callback either with the legacy callback API or with the generic callback (new since version 12.9). Take a look at the examples `bendersatsp.py` and `bendersatsp2.py` shipped with CPLEX. Focus on functions `__call__`  in the former and `invoke` in the latter. Replace the various `separate` functions called from there with code that separates your constraints.